# I need someone to look over some javascript code for me because I'm getting an error that says syntax error

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I need someone to look at this code. I am a beginner at javascript and I can't find the error(s) in this code I made.

```
 var user = prompt ("Are you a goblin, knight, troll, human, or wizard?").toLowerCase()
var name = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase()
var gender = prompt("Are you male or female?").toLowerCase()
switch(user) {
        case 'goblin':
            console.log("Hello, you are going to have a fun journey as a goblin");
            var meetAnt = prompt ("You run into a giant ant eater, you can attack or run. Do you choose to attack?").toLowerCase()
            if(meetAnt = yes) {
                console.log ("you stab him in the eye, but then he hits you with his trunk. You are injured");
                var finishAnt = prompt("you can either risk your life and finish him, or try to run away. Do you finish him?").toLowerCase()
                if(finishAnt = yes) {
                    return true;
                    console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")
                }
                else if(finishAnt = no) {
                    return false;
                    console.log("You run away and barley make it, you are badly hurt");
                    else {
                        console.log("sorry thats not an option")
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return true;
                console.log("You run past the ant eater and get to saftey. You are very lucky")
            }
            break;
        case 'knight':
            console.log("Hello, you are going to have a fun journey as a knight");
            var dayFight = prompt("You are versing the goblins in a fight, you need to choose how many days you go to fight(1-100). Remember if you choose too little days then you won't have stayed long enough to win the fight but if you stay to long you have more of a chance of dying or getting injured").toLowerCase()
            if(dayFight < 40) {
                return false;
                console.log("You did not fight enough days, which has resulted in your kingdome loosing the war to the goblins.");
            }
            else if(dayFight > 60) {
                return false;
                console.log("You have went to war to long and been seriously injured.");
            }
            else if(40<=dayFight=>60) {
                return true;
                console.log("You have been at war for the right amount of time. You have came out of the war with no injuries and you also have defieted the goblins!")
            }
            break;
        case 'troll':
            console.log("Hello, you are going to have a fun journey as a troll");
            var red = true;
            var green = true;
            var yellow = false;
            var blue = false;
            var houseRaid = prompt("You see four huts in the middle of the woods. You can raid two. There is a red hut, blue hut, yellow hut, and green hut. What is one color house that you want to raid?").toLowerCase()
            var doorPick = prompt("Do you want to enter throuhg the back door or front door?").toLowerCase()
            if(doorPick||houseRaid = "red"||"green" && "back door") {
                return true;
                console.log("You raided these houses and left before any villagers would see you");
            }
            else {
                return false;
                console.log("You raided those houses, but one of them was a booby trap and you are now captured");
            }
            break;
        case 'human':
            console.log("Hello, you are going to have a fun journey as a human");
            var reinforceFound = prompt("You know a storm is comming and you have to reinforce your hut, but you only have enough material to reinforce either your lower foundations or higher foundations. Which do you inforce? Higher or lower?").toLowerCase()
            if(reinforceFound = lower) {
                return false;
                console.log("The storms winds pushed down the top of your house and caved in your roof.");
            }
            else if(reinforceFound = higher) {
                return true;
                console.log("The storm did not do that much damage to your house due to your reinforced higher foundations. Good choice");
            }
            else {
                console.log("sorry but that is not an option. Pick either 'higher', or 'lower'")
            }
            break;
        case 'wizard':
            console.log("Hello, you are going to have a fun journey as a wizard");
            var blood = true;
            var dust = true;
            var wings = false;
            var mushrooms = false;
            var postion = prompt("You are working on a new healing potion but you do not know what you need to add to finish it. You have 4 ingrediants; blood, dust, wings, mushrooms. Pick one too add. (WARNING: Pick carefully because if you choose the wrong ingerdiant, then your potion will be ruined.)").toLowerCase()
            if(postion = wings || mushroom) {
                console.log("You picked a bad ingrediant and now your potion is ruined.");
            }
            else if(postion = dust || blood) {
                console.log("you picked the right ingrediant and your potion is okay")
            }
            else {
                console.log("sorry but that is not an option");
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Sorry but that is not a character in the game");
};
```

I am making this code for a lesson in the website www.codecademy.com. It is supposed to be a small part of a game. Sorry there is so much, I couldn't narrow down anymore were the error is coming from.

Comment: '=' in comparisons should be '==', at least. And comparing with `yes` and `no` is meaningless: `'yes'` and `'no'` (string literals) should be used instead. Also, why put anything into your `if-else` branches after `return`? It won't be executed by the very definition of `return`.

Comment: Toss it through here - http://jshint.com/ - it will help you along

Comment: Is this meant to execute inside of a function? `return` is meaningless otherwise. If you open up the development console in your browser, it should show you the specific line throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because you are missing an ending bracket at line 18 (of the posted code). This:

```
else {
```

should be:

```
} else {
```

The missing bracket means that there is no matching `if` before the `else`.

Some other problems in the code, but perhaps not all of them:

---

You are missing semicolons at the end of many statements. They are not required when the statement ends where the line ends, but they are recommended.

---

You have a problems with comparisons like these:

```
if(meetAnt = yes) {
```

The comparison operator is `==` (or `===`), and you are missing delimiters around the string value, so it would be interpreted as a variable name. It should be:

```
if(meetAnt == "yes") {
```

---

In comparisons like these you get unexpected results:

```
if(dayFight < 40) {
```

The variable contains a string, so the value `40` is converted to the string `"40"` for the comparison, and they are compared as strings instead of numbers. That means that for example `"100" < "40"`. You should parse the input string to a number:

```
dayFight = parseInt(dayFight, 10);
```

---

With comparisons like this the syntax is wrong:

```
else if(40<=dayFight=>60) {
```

Comparing one value using two operators doesn't work, and there is no `=>` operator. You need two conditions:

```
else if(40 <= dayFight && dayFight <= 60) {
```

---

In comparisons like this you have used the `||` operator wrong (and the wrong comparison operator and the missing string delimiters):

```
if(postion = wings || mushroom) {
```

It's used between conditions, not to compare multiple values in one condition:

```
if(postion == "wings" || postion == "mushroom") {
```

---

When you put a statement after `return`, that statement will not be executed as the code exits the function at the `return` statement:

```
return true;
console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")
```

Reorder them:

```
console.log("congratulations you have killed the aint eater!")
return true;
```